# Volume License for Windows 8 Enterprise

Tags: windows, windows-8, volume-license

I'm not clear on how we can upgrade to Windows 8 Enterprise from my existing Windows 7 Pro. It 's mentioned [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203353.aspx) that we can upgrade to Windows 8 Enterprise from a Windows 7 Pro (Volume License). What is Volume License exactly? Is the enterprise edition only available for organizations?

Comment: If you don't know what a Volume license is, then you don't have one, which means you will have to installed Windows 8 Enterprise from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

To know about Volume Licensing, see here http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/how-volume-licensing-works.aspx

It is quite obvious from its name, that it is meant for Organisations (who would buy thru Volume Licensing).

You would not be eligible for the same  - you would need to buy a copy of Windows 8 to install it.

However, if you purchased your PC recently, you may be eligible for certain upgrade plans. Check here: http://www.windowsupgradeoffer.com/en-US